# SQL: Determining "Min" or "Least" of Average

Tags: sql

I'm doing an analysis of cost per product by supplier and have been stuck for a while trying to work out the granularity or procedure of this SQL code. Table looks like something below:

```
Supplier      ProductCount     Cost
SupA          2                564.00
SupA          1                200.00
SupB          3                650.00
SupC          2                600.00
etc.
```

And what I want is a table that contains a summary like so:

```
Supplier      TotalCount       TotalCost     AvgCost     MinAvgCost (expected)
SupA          3                764.00        254.67      ?(200)
SupB          3                650.00        216.67      ?(216.67)
SupC          2                600.00        300.00      ?(300.00)
```

I can do the others by a simple SUM Function, but I'm confused as to how to do the MinAvgCost, since if I simply do a SELECT MIN(AvgCost) it will return to me the same value as the AvgCost.

How do I define that the code should divide Cost and ProductCount on each row, then return to me the MIN value of that formula?

Comment: it would help if you can tag the dbms being used. also fill in the `?`s in the expected result.

Comment: Why in ur result query TotalCost for `SupA` is 564? shoudn't be 764 ?

Comment: And what is the formula for `minavgcost`?

Comment: @esiprogrammer absolutely right - edit.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - the formula should be the Minimum amount of AvgCost at it's most granular level. Expected results are filled in ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is probably what you want ?](http://rextester.com/XOCUI32566)

(I've done it with MySql, you may need some change on other DB)

```
SELECT 
    Supplier, 
    sum(ProductCount) AS TotalCount,  
    sum(Cost) AS TotalCost,
    (sum(Cost) / sum(ProductCount)) AS AvgCost,
    min(Cost/ProductCount) AS MinAvgCost
FROM t
GROUP BY `Supplier`
```

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: @Lazarius you're welcome ;) BTW, what was your DB ? MySQL ?

Comment: Actual DB itself is HP Vertica, but the front-end uses SQL.